# If $\langle T(x),y \rangle=0$ then $T=T_0$ - Prove this result if the equality holds for all $x,y$ in some basis for $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear operator on an inner product space $V$. If $\langle T(x),y \rangle=0$ for all $x,y \in V$ then $T=T_0$ where it means zero transformation.
Prove this result if the equality holds for all $x,y$ in some basis for $V$.

The hint says use the theorem below.
[let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over $F$ and suppose that {$v_1,\dots,v_n$} is a bsis for $V$. For $w_1,\dots,w_n$ in $W$, there exists exactly one linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow W$ such that $T(v_i)=w_i$.]
But I don't know how to apply this.
Actually the true meaning of this question is still ambiguous to me.
It means that $x,y \in \beta$ for some basis $\beta$? And $\langle T(x),y \rangle=0$?

Comment: How is it defined $T_0$?

Comment: I *think* the second sentence is supposed to be "If $\langle Tx,y\rangle = 0$ for all $x,y \in V$, then $T = 0$."

Comment: Yes, $T_0$ means zero transformation.

Comment: And obviously no hypothesis on $\langle \cdot \rangle$?

Comment: @RicPed Yes, it's a normal inner product. Sine $\langle T(x),y \rangle=0$ for all $y \in V$, it means that $T(x)=0$ for all $x \in V$ so $T=T_0$.

Comment: Usually the zero transformation is just written $0$.

Comment: Yeah yeah 'cause I've dealt only with scalar products and not generalization of them so I was unsure of which property I can use:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably what the question means is that if $v_k$ is a basis for $V$ and $w_k$ is a basis for $W$, then $\langle Tv_i, w_j \rangle = 0$ for all $i,j$.

Let $v_k$ be a basis for $V$ and $w_k$ be a basis for $W$. Then if $x \in V$ we can write $x = \sum_i \alpha_i v_i$ and similarly for any $y \in W$, we can write $y = \sum_j \beta_j w_j$. Then $\langle Tx, y \rangle = \sum_i \sum_j \alpha_i \beta_j \langle Tv_i, w_j \rangle = 0$. Hence $\langle Tx, y \rangle = 0$ for all $x,y$.

If $\langle Tx, y \rangle = 0$ for all $x,y$, then for each $x$, choose $y=Tx$, then you have $\langle Tx, Tx \rangle = \|Tx\|^2 = 0$. Hence $Tx = 0$ for all $x$, from which it follows that $T=0$.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to prove $T=0$. I want to know if that equality holds for all $x,y$ in some basis of $V$.

Comment: I added a paragraph showing that if it holds for elements of the basis of $V$ and $W$, then it is true generally.

Comment: Just one more question. Why that theorem implys that $\langle T(v_i),w_j \rangle=0$?

Comment: I presume the question was if the equality  holds for $x$ in some basis of $V$ and $y$ in some basis of $W$, then show the result is true generally. So it is an assumption, because it is not true generally, of course (Just take $T$ to be the identity operator for example).

Comment: Oh, so I wonder why $\langle T(x),y \rangle = \sum_i\alpha_i\sum_j\beta_j \langle T(v_i),w_j \rangle=0$ means $\langle T(v_i),w_j \rangle=0$. Is that what you mean, right?

Comment: No, if I understand the question correctly, you have it the wrong way around. The question is, if $\langle T x, y \rangle = 0$ for $x$ in a basis of $V$ and $y$ in a basis of $W$, then show that $\langle T x, y \rangle = 0$ for **all** $x,y$.

Comment: The relevant part of your question is: "Prove this result if the equality holds for all $x,y$ in some basis for $V$." (Except it should read $y$ in a basis for $W$, since the inner product is defined on $W$.)

Comment: Now I understand clearly!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: And maybe if I use your way then I don't have to use that theorem I mentioned, right? Thanks again!

Comment: If I got the question right, you don't.

Comment: Not a counter-example.... but something you should think about.

Let T = [0, 1 ; -1 , 0]

And $x=(x_1 x_2)^t$.  Apologies,on poor scripts for $T$ (I don't know how to write this!?)
$<x|Tx> = <x|(x_2,-x_1)^t> = x_1 x_2 - x_2 x_1 = 0$

Comment: @Squirtle: Any skew-symmetric matrix will have the same result. I'm not sure I see the relevance to the OP's question?

Comment: The point.... (which I do think is important) is that the vector space has to be complex.  My example falls apart the moment I extend to the complex case because the inner product I have will be non-zero (subtracting the complex conjugate from a complex number).  In other words, it's not enough to have this result in a real space.

Comment: This is a completely different issue. The OPs question has nothing to do with the underlying field. The point is that it is sufficient to define a bilinear form $V \times W \to \mathbb{F}$ on the basis $\{ v_i \otimes w_j \}$.